# Dynamic page title in separate header component

Tags: next.js

So I have just started working on this project a couple days ago and for now its basically a navbar, a header, and a container for routes(pages).

My header is in a separate component from the pages components and the header is supposed to display the title of the page where are currently on.

How can I dynamically display the title of the current page in the header component?

I have tried this but it obviously returns the pathname and not a page title like I want

```
export default function header() {
  const route = useRouter()

  return (
    <header className='header'>
      <h1 className='page-title'>{route.asPath}</h1>
      <div className='header-icons'>
        <div className='header-icon'><Notifications_icon /></div>
        <div className='header-icon'><User_icon /></div>
      </div>
    </header>
  )
}
```

Comment: Where and how do you set the title of the page? Can you not use React context to make the title available from there to the header?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use **document.title**
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/title

or you pass as a props the title you want as you also pass this title to the  tag of 'next/head'

```
import Head from 'next/head';

const Page = () =>(
<>
  <Head>
    <title>{text}</title>
  </Head>
  <Header title={text} />
</>
)

export default Page
```

Comment: Second option wont work because the header and page components are different. First option could work but its not very flexible. I was thinking of returning the first parameter of the pathname, is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve this by wrapping the app inside the layout component and give the name to each component, then get it through by passing props down to the header.

This is my app component:

```
export default function App({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {

return (
        <Layout>
          <Component {...pageProps} />
        </Layout>
  );
}
```

Layout component:

```
 export default function Layout({ children }: LayoutProps) {
  const PageName: string = (children as any).type.displayName;
  return (
    <>
  <Head>
    <title>{PageName}</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
   </Head>
   <main>
     {children}
    <Footer />
  </main>
    </>
  );
}
```

You can add your header component in it and pass the page name as prop.
Now the only thing left to do, is to goto each page and outside the page(main function in the page file) function. Give the name to the page by using the following method:

```
Page.displayName = "Page Name";
```

This also works on production.